# Maven build error with net.sf.launch4j

Tags: maven, launch4j

Trying to package a maven's project using akathist artefacts :

```
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <classifier>core</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Any clue with this error ? (UPDATED)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j (l4j- on project winwrap: Execution l4j- of goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j failed: A required class was missing while executing com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j: net/sf/launch4j/BuilderException
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/akathist/maven/plugins/launch4j/launch4j-maven-plugin/1.7/launch4j-maven-plugin-1.7.jar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/net/sf/launch4j/launch4j/3.5.0/launch4j-3.5.0-core.jar
    [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.4/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
    [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
    [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
    [ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
    [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException
```

FULL ST:

```
WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/hypatie/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/hypatie/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/hypatie/client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/hypatie/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/hypatie/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.launch4j:launch4j:jar:core:3.5.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/akathist/maven/plugins/launch4j/launch4j-maven-plugin/1.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The metadata /Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/akathist/maven/plugins/launch4j/launch4j-maven-plugin/1.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-akathist-repository.xml is invalid: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17) 
[WARNING] The POM for com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ winwrap ---
[INFO] Deleting /Developer/wksp/ubiclient/webdav-server/trunk/winwrap/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ webdav-server-winwrap ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Developer/wksp/ubiclient/webdav-server/trunk/winwrap/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ webdav-server-winwrap ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ webdav-server-winwrap ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Developer/wksp/server/trunk/winwrap/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webdav-server-winwrap ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ webdav-server-winwrap ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Developer/wksp/ubiclient/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ server-winwrap ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /Developer/wksp/server/trunk/winwrap/target/-webdav-server-winwrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j (l4j- @     oct. 26, 2014 4:19:25 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
AVERTISSEMENT: Error injecting: com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.Launch4jMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/launch4j/BuilderException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2012)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:629)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:831)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:954)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:950)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 54 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.871s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 26 16:19:25 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j (l4j- on project server-winwrap: Execution l4j- of goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j failed: A required class was missing while executing com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7:launch4j: net/sf/launch4j/BuilderException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/com/akathist/maven/plugins/launch4j/launch4j-maven-plugin/1.7/launch4j-maven-plugin-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/net/sf/launch4j/launch4j/3.5.0/launch4j-3.5.0-core.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.4/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/l2c/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException
```

Comment: Can you past the full stacktrace...

Comment: Full stacktrace added for the module.

Comment: Delete your full local repository and restart build. Check if you have some kind of transfer errors/warnings during download.

Comment: [ERROR] Plugin com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-
[ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/akathist/maven/plugins/launch4j/launch4j-maven-plugin/1.7/launch4j-maven-plugin-1.7.pom: end tag name </block> must match start tag name <link> from line 17 (position: TEXT seen ...eralAppC/bugkicker/rekicker.css" type="text/css">\n        </block>... @18:17)  @ line 18, column 17

Comment: Still no solution: last launch4j release unstable at the moment.